# C# Modificar Reporte RDLC en tiempo de ejecucion del sistema

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, rdlc

buenas tardes, estoy desarrollando un sistema en C# (.NET 6.0), y estoy en la parte de informes y reportes , estoy utilizando RDLC en Windos Forms para realizar los mismos.
Queria saber si existe la posibilidad de mover los controles que agregue o modificar el texto de los mismos en tiempo de ejecucion del sistema, por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi esta el informe abierto, queria saber si desde ahi el informe se puede moficiar (es decir se puede cambiar el texto del titulo, y modificar los labels, o cosas por el estilo, tambien saber si se pueden agregas mas controles , etc)...

En caso de que no se pueda y haya algun programa que no sea visual studio en el que se puede modificar el informe tambien me gustaria saberlo!

Gracias..

Les comparto mi codigo de como estoy generando la impresion:

```
  public void imprimirComprobanteFiscal(int comprobanteFiscalId)
    {
        Comprobantes_Fiscales oComprobanteFiscal = new Comprobantes_Fiscales().GetComprobanteFiscal(comprobanteFiscalId);
        if(oComprobanteFiscal.comprobanteFiscalId > 0)
        {
            dataSetComprobanteFiscal.Clear();
            DataRow drComprobanteFiscal;
            drComprobanteFiscal = dataSetComprobanteFiscal.Tables["dtComprobantesFiscales"].NewRow();
            drComprobanteFiscal["dcComprobanteFiscalId"] = Convert.ToInt32(oComprobanteFiscal.comprobanteFiscalId);
            drComprobanteFiscal["dcComprobanteFiscalDescripcion"] = oComprobanteFiscal.descripcion.ToString().ToUpper();
            drComprobanteFiscal["dcComprobanteFiscalImporte"] = Convert.ToDecimal(oComprobanteFiscal.importe);
            dataSetComprobanteFiscal.Tables["dtComprobantesFiscales"].Rows.Add(drComprobanteFiscal);

            string ArchivoRDLC = "C:\\storesys\\Reports\\rptFactura.rdlc";
            ReportDataSource[] oRDS = new ReportDataSource[1];

            oRDS[0] = new ReportDataSource("Comprobante_Fiscal", dataSetComprobanteFiscal.Tables["dtComprobantesFiscales"]);

            frmReportViewerRDLC oVisor = new frmReportViewerRDLC();
            oVisor.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ArchivoRDLC;
            oVisor.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            oVisor.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(oRDS[0]);
            oVisor.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            oVisor.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¡Ahora sí hermano, ahora sí, la pregunta está perfecta! Gracias por la paciencia. Ahora bien, la última vez que utilicé Crystal Report, existía un archivo de extensión `.rptp` o `.rpt` no recuerdo exactamente cuál, lo que sí recuerdo es que estaba al costado del `.rdlc`, la cosa es que ese era el archivo que se modificaba y daba lo mismo si estaba en ejecución el programa o no. Considera que esto fue hace como 10-11 años, de todas maneras, ahí va el aporte. Saludos :D

Comment: Un dato adicional, en caso estés utilizando una impresora matricial, en la modificación de los controles, siempre utiliza la regla física, no te fies de la regla digital, usa una regla física y mueve los controles lentamente, hacer que se imprima exactamente donde uno quiere con esa impresora, es todo un entrenamiento de paciencia impresionante.

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx probare de esta forma tambien capaz que es mas optima.

De todas formas comparto lo que hice averiguando tambien:
No logre hacerlo en el tiempo de ejecucionn pero instale el Report Builder y con eso salio funcionando al menos para modificar el reporte sin utilizar el visual studio.

Gracias por el aporte fredy, tengo entendido que eso para Crystal Report funciona bien porque lo he probado en mi proyecto de la mañana y me funciono, asi que con tu aporte mas lo que logre averiguar pude solucionar el problema en ambos sistemas!
Saludos y gracias (:

Comment: Un placer colaborar estimado, ¿ves que la mala onda es inexistente? Todo fresh~. Por otro lado, coloca en la parte inferior donde dice "Tu Respuesta" los pasos que seguiste para dar solución a tu escenario, entre más detalles, mejor, de este modo pasan 2 cosas: 1. Te conviertes en el héroe de más usuarios que tienen el mismo escenario o un escenario muy similar. 2. Aportas a la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas), recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada en el check del costado de la respuesta, solo el que hizo la pregunta puede aceptarlo. Como es autorespuesta, espera 24 horas.

Comment: Los textos los puedes cambiar usando parametros de reporte

Answer (score 1):

En los reportes RDL puedes definir "parametros" estos parametros lo puedes utilizar para cualquier cosa, por ejemplo

- Parametros para la consulta (si el reporte es quien realiza la consulta en su fuente de datos)
- Parametros para definir elementos del reporte (visualizacion, labels, etc)

Estos parametros lo puedes utilizar en tus label/etiquetas, [Como visualizar un parametro de reporte en un campo label en RDL (en ingles)](https://allcode.com/how-to-display-a-report-parameter-label-field-in-a-microsoft-visual-studio-report/)

Ejemplo de codigo para enviar el parametro "en tiempo de ejecución"

```
    /// Create the sales order number report parameter  
    ReportParameter salesOrderNumber = new ReportParameter();  
    salesOrderNumber.Name = "SalesOrderNumber";  
    salesOrderNumber.Values.Add("SO43661");  

    // Set the report parameters for the report  
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(  
        new ReportParameter[] { salesOrderNumber });
```

Otro ejemplo, que lo respondi aqui [Foros de MSDN ASP.NET ¿como usar reportes de reporting services desde asp.net pasando parametros?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/88b5c357-d60c-43cc-9935-8d8bcc462562/como-usar-reportes-de-reporting-services-desde-aspnet-pasando-parametros?forum=netfxwebes)

```
    //Creando Parametros
    var fechaDesde = new ReportParameter();
    salesOrderNumber.Name = "FechaDesde";
    salesOrderNumber.Values.Add(fechaDesde.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

    var fechaHasta= new ReportParameter("fechaHasta", fechaHasta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    
    
    //Seteamos los parametros en el reporte (modo local)
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(
        new ReportParameter[] { fechaDesde, fechaHasta })
```

IMPORTANTE: No recuerdo como es en modo winform el reporte local creo que es mirando tu codigo

```
    reportViewer1.LocalReport
```

LocalReport o ServerReport es el modo del control ReportViewer ya que el reporte puede estar en un servidor de reportes

Enlaces para ayudar

- [Foros de MSDN ASP.NET ¿como usar reportes de reporting services desde asp.net pasando parametros?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/88b5c357-d60c-43cc-9935-8d8bcc462562/como-usar-reportes-de-reporting-services-desde-aspnet-pasando-parametros?forum=netfxwebes)
- [Use the WinForms ReportViewer Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [How to display report parameter Label field in RDLC reports](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/how-to-display-report-parameter-label-field-in-rdlc-reports/ba-p/319019)

Espero que te sira de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo voy a tener en cuenta y probar tambien a esto, lo unico que hice fue instalar el report builder para poder modificar los archivos y que queden guardados, pero tambien voy a ver esta opcion , gracias !